# android ListView ,setSelection() has no effect after setFlags(...FULLSCREEN)

Tags: android, listview, fullscreen

Now I have this problem when:

1. In my Asynctask, I have a ProgressDialog over this Listview that is constantly updated and scrolling automatically (I use something like mListview.setSelection(mData.size()-1); to scroll it )
2. I want it to be fullscreen when it's not finished or canceled, which I think is pretty easy by   Window dialogWindow = mProgressDialog.getWindow();
             dialogWindow.setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN, WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
3. I also want it to stop being fullscreen( i.e. I want the status bar shown) when it's finished. And I want the first item in the Listview shown as well.
4. -------------------- This 's when the problem occurrs.--------------------

I use like 
          dialogWindow.setFlags(0, WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);

and it's working well. The status bar appears.

then I use mListview.setSelection(0), which I suppose can bring the me first item.

HOWEVER, it has no effect at all. Any idea how this happens or how to solve it? Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

you can try this method, it maybe helpful to you..

```
http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ListView.html#smoothScrollToPosition(int)



public void smoothScrollToPosition (int position)

Since: API Level 8
Smoothly scroll to the specified adapter position. The view will scroll such that the         indicated position is displayed.

Parameters
position    Scroll to this adapter position.
```

Comment: I think I have tried it once and ended up with very bizarre behavior: it scrolled a bit, and stopped prematurely without reaching the selected item. What's more, I'd rather have it immediately focused on the first item without any scrolling.

Answer (score 0):

You have to use

```
mListview.clearFocus();
```

before calling

```
mListview.requestFocusFromTouch();
mListview.setSelection(0);
```

in a post method of mListView.